# AccessViolation exception when form with AxWindowsMediaPlayer closed

Tags: winforms, .net-3.5, activex, windows-media-player, wmp

I have a `AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer` on a form. When I close the form, I get "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." exception. It is OK with hiding the form but not with closing. Everything's fine when the component is removed from the form.

This is Winforms .Net3.5.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This was happening to me, and it was when closing the form during a key press.

Seems the WMP control will cause problems if it has a key event to process.

Example with Form.KeyPreview = True

```
Sub Form_KeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
 AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Causes an Access Violation.

```
Sub Form_KeyDown(e As KeyEventArgs)
 e.Handled = True
 AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Closes cleanly, as the key press is blocked from reaching the WMP control.

Same thing happens when the form is closed as will dispose of the control.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when working with ActiveX objects in .NET applications it is necessary to force garbage collection on exit.  I generally do this in Form_Closing using:

```
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
GC.Collect()
```

Also, if you have setup any event handlers for the object, you will want to disconnect them explicitly.  I've found on a number of occasions that ActiveX objects will still remain active in the garbage bin and will attempt to call the event handler even after they have been disposed.

It may also be worth it to make sure playback has stopped before you try to dispose of the object.

Comment: i have found that indeed doing a `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Dispose();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();` inside the `_FormClosing()` event, did help.

Comment: nah it doesnt... still violation.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX objects may have some sensitive dependencies on being closed in the correct order when the parent form is closed, otherwise they may go on living until gc runs - try looking through the interface for the control for any methods that look like they may have to do with closing, or destroying the object and calling those.

Comment: I've tried stopping, reseting source URL, closing, disposing but no luck. Can we get any closer to the problem by finding where the error originated? I haven't check event log yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
}
```

simply found the method on the doc http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562388(v=vs.85).aspx
I thought I'd give it a go. it seems much better now.

Comment: no after all no good either. we can do whatever we like, this control is bugged, end of the story. If I had time I would scrap this microsoft horror and use VLC libraries.