# AccessViolation (0xc0000005) before video starts playing

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, access-violation, axwindowsmediaplayer

My Windows Form Application is closing unexpectedly and the debug console says AccessViolation 0xc0000005 before starting to play the video.

I'm starting the video with the following code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Program Files\MyApp\Video.mp4";
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

If video ends close it and exit from form:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if(e.newState == 8)
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.close();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Player's designer code

```
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Enabled = true;
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Name = "axWindowsMediaPlayer1";
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("axWindowsMediaPlayer1.OcxState")));
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1906, 1066);
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.TabIndex = 2;
this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1.PlayStateChange += new AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(this.axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange);
```

Debug Output:

> The program '[(PID)] game.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.

I have tried to use try-catch but the error isn't being catched. But the problem isn't try-catch.
Application is running with administrator rights.

Application's event from Windows Event Viewer:

D3D9.DLL

> Faulting application name: game.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x58a1bd65
>   Faulting module name: D3D9.DLL, version: 10.0.14393.447, time stamp: 0x5819bcea
>   Exception code: 0xc0000005
>   Fault offset: 0x0000000000010207
>   Faulting process id: 0x189c
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01d2860e39d0d6e7
>   Faulting application path: C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\game.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\D3D9.DLL
>   Report Id: 21a37f31-b9d0-4137-ad79-35d608e10916
>   Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

NET Runtime

> Application: game.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: expection code c0000005, expection address 00007FFFD7490207

My PC is Windows 10 Single Language 1607 (14393.693)

**TINY NOTE:** This error throwns all of my Projects after created or edited 1 month ago.

***UPDATE:*** The same errors are thrown on the Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1 and Windows 7 Virtual Machines and my PC

Comment: `AccessViolationException` is by default not catched. Check the Event Viewer it should hold more information about the crash

Comment: Ofir Winegarten Windows Event Viewer, catch this but i don't understand anything: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/3TWM1

Comment: There should be more info than what you've posted. There might be two different errors in the logs

Comment: Copy the text from the general tab not detailed

Comment: Have you tried playing it in a video player like Microsoft or VLC?

Comment: No problem on VLC, GOM, Windows Media Player. Video is playing well on this players.

Comment: where/when do you get that error message?

Comment: have you tried the solutions from [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/685199/238902)?

Comment: yes, but don,t work and before starting the video

Comment: Form opens, waits 5 seconds and crashes

Comment: try add this in the app.config  under the configuration/runtime element, it will allow you to catch the exception and then maybe you discover more details: <legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy enabled="true"/>

Comment: I tried this code on first crashing but it didn't work. App isn't catch error

Comment: Anyone have idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for bumping this thread, but maybe this can help someone..
I had a same problem, the workaround was to change the default graphic processor from external (nVidia) GPU to Integrated (Intel) GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Still happening in 2021. Finally fixed it by installing the latest Nvidia drivers and in the Nvidia Control Panel -> Adjust image settings with preview, select "Use my preference emphasizing: **Performance**".

The default was Quality and it was causing problems. Change it to Performance and the error should go away.